# Suspend Akka Actors

Tags: scala, blocking, akka

I am trying to use Akka to implement the following (I think I'm trying to use Akka the proper way):

I have a system where I have *n* resource listeners.  Essentially a resource listener is an entity that will listen on an input resource and publish what it sees (i.e. polling a database, tailing a log file, etc.).

So I want to use Akka actors to do these little bits of work units (listening on a resource).  I've noticed that the Akka gives me a thread pool of *t* threads which may be less than the number of listeners.  Unfortunately for me, getting a message from these resource listeners might be blocking, so it could take seconds, minutes, before the next message pops up.

Is there any way to suspend a resource listener so it leaves the thread to another actor and we'll come back to it a little later in time?

Comment: You could write an actor that pings the resource listeners and make the listeners sleep until they get a ping.

Comment: Do you plan to register the *listeners* explicitly ,let's say, in a collection, and calling them explicitly from your resource code like calling some `fireResourceEvent` on each of them when the input publishes something?

Comment: Well the actual resource logic would be more like a polling of the resource, i.e. calling a getMessage() method on the resource object and then publishing that message.  So the resourceListener has-a resource, unlike the resource listener is notified by the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should try to avoid blocking operations in actors. For file IO, there are asynchronous libraries and for some databases, too. If that is not an option for you, you can set change the default dispatcher so that the underlying thread pool expands as needed.

Comment: The scheduler or the dispatcher? Seems like a PinnedDispatcher has a thread-per-actor.

Comment: I meant dispatcher. Changed it.

Comment: A PinnedDispatcher doesn't seem a good idea, it's like dedicating a thread per listener to poll, which looks to me the opposite of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @pagoda_5b: that's why I said that non-blocking IO is preferable

Comment: I would also look at the **Blocking** paragraph on the document for [Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) in Scala 2.10

Comment: Seems like the PinnedDispatcher is a viable short-term solution as we're playing with legacy APIs that are blocking.

Answer (score 3):

## Executive Summary

What you want is for your producer API (the resources) to be asynchronous, or at least support non-blocking operations (so that you can do polling). If the API does not support that, then there is no way to retrofit this property, not even using the almighty actors ;-)

## Strategies for Different Situations

### Only Blocking API

If the resources only support the blocking `getWhatever()` method of retrieving things, then you must allocate one thread per resource. An Actor with a PinnedDispatcher could be a way to do this. But be aware that the actor will not be responsive while waiting for events from the resource.

### Non-Blocking but Synchronous API

If there is a `peek()` or `poll()` method on the resource API, you can use one actor per resource, have them share a thread (or pool) and schedule the polling as required (i.e. every 100ms or whatever you need). This has the huge advantage that nobody is actually blocked and the whole system remains responsive. But latency for event reception will be of the order of your schedule interval.

### Proper Asynchronous API

If you have enough good karma to encounter a nice asynchronous API, then simply register a callback which will send a message to the actor whenever an event occurs. Sadly, this is not the norm.

#### PS:

The JVM does not support wrapping up the current call stack, doing something else and return to that same processing state later. A method can only be popped of the stack when it is actually finished.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to call your blocking APIs inside Futures.   The Futures should use an ExecutionContext (thread pool) that is separate from the Actors' ExecutionContext.

See [this blog post](http://letitcrash.com/post/30509298968/case-study-an-auto-updating-cache-using-actors) for an example (specifically CacheActor.findValueForSender).